# CakePHP-Ask about the logo and other affections?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, cakephp

Sorry I have to make new question like this, because I don't know the keywords to ask for this  problem.

I am studying CakePHP. When I make the page to query the list user from DB and I make the page navigation inside. Everything was ok but when I add my logo into the top of website. It will ok if I stay on my page, but when I click to navigation page. It will disappear (look like the link of image is broken).

This one is ok when I don't click to navigation page.

[image]

And this one is broken.

[image]

**My question is: how to fix this problem.** Because not only this logo, but also some things else have the same problem too, I want it that wil be appeared on everypage or action. Can anybody help me about this.

**Update:** I have find the way to solve this problem. We use the helper to make the img. Instead, we use HTML  tag for show the img. We use the helper in CakePHP like:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->image
(
    'CakeIcon.jpg', 
    array
    (
        'alt'=>'td-cakephp', 
        'height'=>'50px', 
        'width'=>'50px'
    )
);
```

?>

I update for someone research this situation that can be solved more easily.

Comment: Can you please provide more information: are you using the HTML Helper to produce the image? (if not, you should be) Are you using the CakePHP `BASE_URL` constant to prefix your path? (if not, and you aren't using the HTML helper, you DEFINITELY should be). Please provide the output HTML for your image tag.

Comment: Properly use absolute URLs relative to the domain root. Then it all works out of the box. The helpers if used provide you with this path automatically. PS: And dont use named params, use query strings.

Comment: scrowler, mark: Maybe I didn't know about this. I just used HTML tag to define this IMG in template. How can I do with HTML helper? It had many things I didn't know because I just study about CakePHP. Thanks